# TypeError: store.getState is not a function when upgrading react-redux-firebase to v ^3.9.0

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, redux

Having trouble getting `firebaseConnect` to provide the redux store in an unfamiliar codebase

Current Versions:  
`"react-native": "0.63.4"`  
`"react-redux": "^7.2.2"`  
`"@react-native-firebase/app": "^10.3.0"`

When trying to build on iOS, getting this error:  
`TypeError: store.getState is not a function. (In 'store.getState()', 'store.getState' is undefined)`

This is where the error is pointing to:

```
export default compose<any>(
  connect(
    (state: State): Partial<MVProps> => ({
      myUserId: get(state, 'user.profile.id'),
      villagers: getFromIds(state.users, state.users.villagers),
    })
  ),
  firestoreConnect(props => [
    {
      collection: 'rooms',
      where: [
        [`type`, '==', 'userToUser'],
        [`users.${props.myUserId}`, '==', true],
      ],
      storeAs: 'myRooms',
    },
  ]),
  firestoreConnect((_, store) => {
    const state = store.getState() as State;
    return flatten(
      defaultTo(state.firestore.ordered.myRooms, []).map((r: Room) =>
        keys(r.users).map((userId: string) => ({
          collection: 'users',
          where: ['userId', '==', userId],
          storeAs: 'myRoomsUsers',
        }))
      )
    );
  }),
  connect(
    (state: State): Partial<MVProps> => ({
      myRooms: state.firestore.ordered.myRooms,
      myRoomsUsers: state.firestore.data.myRoomsUsers,
    })
  )
)(view);
```

This error happened while upgrading `"react-redux-firebase"` from `"^2.1.6"` to `"^3.9.0"`. Following the [migrating to v3 guide](https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/v3-migration-guide.html), this is what the store creation and `ReactReduxFirebaseProvider` look like:

```
export let store;
export async function getStore() {
  try {
    if (store) {
      return store;
    }

    firestore();
    const envCompose = __DEV__ ? composeWithDevTools : compose;
    const finalCreateStore = envCompose(applyMiddleware(...middleware)
    )(createStore);

    store = finalCreateStore(reduceReducers(rootReducer, crossSliceReducer));

    return store;
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

```
    const reduxFirebaseConfig = {
      enableRedirectHandling: false
    };

    const reduxFirebaseProps = {
      firebase,
      config: reduxFirebaseConfig,
      dispatch: this.state.store.dispatch,
      createFirestoreInstance,
      initializeAuth: false,
    };

    return (
      <Provider store={this.state.store}>
        <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...reduxFirebaseProps}>
          <RouterWithRedux
            getSceneStyle={this.getSceneStyle}
            scenes={AppRoutes}
          />
        </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
```

Does anyone know why we are getting this error?